# Update Vuex only if data is new (different from existing)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I use vuex store in my application to store news items from feed. Idea is that if user will navigate to other page and come back on the feed page, posts from store should be visible and loading new data should happen on background.

This works fine but problem occurs when data in background is loaded. When it happens, every single post component is reloaded and mounted again, what creates very bad user experience(since news component is heavy and complicated).

What I want to achieve is to re-render component only if data is new or different. Now every single news component is re-rendered every time, doesn't matter if data is new or the same.

I save data in Vuex this way:

`this.insertOrUpdate({data})`

And in component get them in computed:

```
    news () {
      return News.query().all()
    }
```

and use it in component:

```
  <my-news v-for="item in news"
            :key="item.id"
            :news="item" />
```

Have no idea how to prevent re-rendering those components when data is not changing. Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible and the default behavior usually.   Vue normally does not re-render a component unless you change its unique key.  You may need to show more code to get a definitive answer of what is going on.

Comment: When I set watcher to computed property 'news', I see that it's updating every time, that's why re-rendering happens. key is id, which is not changing for new objects, as well as whole object.